# How To Use ElasticSearch as a search Engine for relational structure in a micro-services envirement

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql, microservices, search-engine

I’m working on an application that is using a relational database `Mysql` for most of the entities and it is constructed in a microservices architecture and each service is using a separate MYSQL database.

[image]

Now I’m trying to implement a search engine for publications using elasticsearch as a middleware funnel to be able to search by all entities that are related to the publication object even from different services with different databases.

**What will be the best way to index the publication object?**

- I have 3 options in mind:

  - Create a full publication type with multi-nested object types?

    - problems:
    - Duplication of all the entities from different services
    - Hard to update for example in case of updating an instruction
  - Create a different publication type with all fields from other objects then normalize the data when inserting or finding the data.

    - problems:
    - normalizing data on inserting and on finding is costly
    - hard to maintain and to update
  - Insert multiple separated types similar to the relational database then do multiple queries to find the final object, for example, if we want to find a publication by user_name we have to find the user first then use the user_id to find the publications.

    - problems:
    - we have to make more than 1 query to get valid results
  - Use has_parent, has_child relation but in this case the child is publication and it is having multiple many-to-one relations so multiple parents.

I could be going in the wrong direction please share your feedback if you think I should use a different technology

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand right.. but if u just want people to search the publications entity, then creating a view with the fields needed would be my first solution. 
can u elaborate more why exactly u thought of elasticsearch ?

second:
i dont think you should worry about duplications when it comes to elasticsearch.

Comment: I want to use elasticsearch as a middleware funnel to search for publications by objects that are related to publication, either, by UserName or by PublicationType. and in this case we have a lot of relations to publication that will be used in the search and they could be located in different services with different mysql database. I hope this could explain more and if its still not clear I can try to give more examples. Thank You